# Custom Link with Product edit form

Tags: product, magento2.3, attributes

I am using magento 2.3 version. I want to add anchor tag after product attribute Name. I tried with **adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form** observer but not working.

I also tried with JS but not able to add <**a class= "product-fuc allow_personalization" href="#" onclick= "sendapproval(this)"> Need Apprvoal** after product name.

Please help me

Comment: Do you require the same in admin product edit?

Comment: Yes, I want in admin product edit form.

Answer (score 0):

Create **Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_edit.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Extension::js/custom_product_edit.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Create  **Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\web\js\custom_product_edit.js**

```
require([
    'jquery',
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $('input[name="product[name]"]').after("<a href='#'>Product Link</a>");
        });

    });
})
```

;

Comment: I tried via JS but link is not adding

Comment: jQuery('input[name="product[name]"]').after("<a href='#'>Product Link</a>");

Place this in the console and try again.

Also, refer this screenshot - https://meetanshi.d.pr/yIy1MY

Comment: I tried and its working but I add some custom ajax on product edit page and this function is calling each and every ajaxstop and also I want to add multiple product attributes and it is not working with multiple fields.

Comment: If you want to do for the multiple attribute product:
input[name="product[name]

You will have to do the live change: input[name="product[name]

and for SKU -  input[name="product[sku]

I hope it helps.